# Whats the best practise to register a express middelware?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am currently in a situation where I need to create a small npm package that delivers an express middelware. The goal is that this middelware registers an Endpoint and delivers some data to a client. Normally I would just write my middelware and the consumer then uses it in the following way:

```
expressApp.use('/mypath', myMiddelware)
```

But I will also deliver an Angular Module that will call this endpoint. Therefore I need to ensure that the endpoints match. With the code above the consumer of my middelware is in control of the path. But I want to achieve that my middelware is control of the path. Therefore I choosed the following approach:

My middelware

```
const myMiddelware = function(res, req, next){
  if(req.path === '/mypath'){
    res.send('some data')
  }
}
```

With this approach the user then consumes the middelware in the following way:

```
expressApp.use(myMiddelware)
```

I searched a lot on the net and did not found an example that uses my approach. I also see the downside of my approach. My middelware will be called on all requests which leads to unnecessary checks.

Has anyone a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your function is supposed to process the request on only one path, then it's not really middleware.  It's a specific request handler.  Just use this:

```
app.get('/mypath', myRequestHandler)
```

Then, it's completely unambiguous.  Your request handler only gets called when the request is `/mypath` and you don't need to check that again inside the request handler and your function isn't called when it isn't the correct path.

If you want to also cover other http verbs, you can specify them separately or you can use `app.all()`.

> My middelware will be called on all requests which leads to unnecessary checks.

Your middleware isn't really middleware.  It's a request handler.  So, don't attach it as middleware.  Attach it as a request handler.  Then, it will ONLY get called when the path matches exactly what you want it to match.